# Failed dependencies when install pxf service

Tags: hawq

When I rpm pxf service in hawq, I got some errors:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
        hadoop >= 2.6.0 is needed by pxf-service-0:3.0.0-root.noarch
        hadoop-hdfs >= 2.6.0 is needed by pxf-service-0:3.0.0-root.noarch
```

What's your advice here ?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure the PXF rpm OS architecture version matches.  For example if the PXF rpm is built for RHEL6 and you are installing on RHEL7 then you may see some dependency issues

Answer (score 1):

Could you please make sure the version of hadoop you are running in the cluster .I guess you might be running a lower version of hadoop .You have to run atleast 2.6 version of hadoop to run the current version of pxf .

Answer (score 0):

The wiki here use the rpm bigtop(hadoop).
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HAWQ/Build+Package+and+Install+with+RPM

It means if I install with rpm(HAWQ 2.2.0), the other ways (using binary hadoop without rpm installs like tar) are not support.

If I install hadoop use tar, I must build HAWQ from source code for now.

Please refer to:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HAWQ-1568